# Audio Call Stops working when Android App goes in Background and device is on Battery Saver Mode

Tags: android, background, webrtc, janus, rtcpeerconnection

My question is more like client side.

I am using Janus AudioBridge Room to make audio call.

Android app works fine in foreground and background mode if device is not on Batter saver mode.

But when device is in Battery saver mode. App gets hold while getting into background.

When we gets back to the app. Call rejoins from there. But if it gets long enough to call 'Keepalive' event. Then app will stops or crash.

I handle this by getting this android permission explicitly from user.
"android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"

Then in battery saver mode. our call does not affects. as our app now can work on background in battery saver mode also.

I don't think this is the best way to do that.

I checked Whatsapp permissions. They are not asking for it.

What Whatsapp or other calling applications are doing to do this in a more proficient way?

Any guide and Clue will be helpful. I appreciate